# Can I send a postcode direct to Google Maps in the URL?

Tags: google-maps

I have a form on my web page that includes a postcode. I want to open a new window and display Google Maps with the data from my postcode form. Ideally something like:

```
www.maps.google.co.uk%postcode=pr87uu
```

Is this something I can do easily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like the Google search you can enter it in the URL as a query, http://maps.google.co.uk/m?q=pr87uu worked perfectly for me. It's a location near Southport, right?

Comment: This doesnt work anymore, now you can use https://www.google.co.uk/maps?q=PR87UU

Answer (score 6):

If you're looking to display it as a normal maps page, you'd want to use `http://google.com/maps?q=SE1+1EB` (Postcode format doesn't matter.)

But if you're looking to use the data from the page, you should be using the [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html). Doing it by requesting a user-end URL could potentially end up with your server getting banned from making requests.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to update this one as I have taken a look. If you use Google Map search it actually sends you now to this URL:

```
https://www.google.co.uk/maps/search/SE1+1EB/
```